# Sporadic bug in Mathematica 7.01.0 MatrixPower and/or Eigensystem functions on floating-point symmetric matrices with repeated eigenvalues

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, version-7

**Note: From the comments submitted below by other StackExchange users it appears that this apparent bug was fixed sometime after version 7.0.1.**

I asked a vague variant of this question a few days ago, but now I will give a concrete example.

Floating point matrices with repeated eigenvalues often arise as the solutions to optimization problems.

The *Mathematica* functions `MatrixPower` and `Eigensystem` appear to have sporadic difficulty dealing with such matrices.  (It is not clear to me whether this is because of numerical instability when trying to determine whether such matrices have nontrivial Jordan blocks, or if there is some other problem.)  I have had to write my own routines for matrix power (and more generally for the functional calculus) to handle such cases, but maybe someone knows a quick fix.

In the notebook

http://tinyurl.com/lhodpdv

I generated the following matrix by random search:  (I'm using Mathematica 7.0.1 on 32-bit Windows)

```
 {{0.461964, -0.314388, -0.138647, -2.23115*10^-6}, 
 {-0.314388, 0.510134, -0.128432, -2.06676*10^-6}, 
 {-0.138647, -0.128432, 0.744719, -9.11454*10^-7}, 
{-2.23115*10^-6, -2.06676*10^-6, -9.11454*10^-7, 0.801359}}
```

This matrix was defined by taking the average of a matrix and its transpose, so it is exactly self-adjoint. (I searched for it by finding rare matrices for which my usual code for inverting the `Eigensystem` function acting on a Hermitian matrix failed.)

The list of eigenvalues

```
{0.801359, 0.801359, 0.801359, 0.1141}
```

has three repeated elements.  All eigenvalues are positive, so *Mathematica* should have no trouble computing the unique positive semidefinite square root of this matrix.

However, using `MatrixPower[%, 1/2]`, *Mathematica* reports that the square root is

```
{0.690223, -0.170008, -0.477225, 0.},
{-0.189862, 0.737704, -0.442063, 0.},
{-0.0837305, -0.0694507, 0.700234, 0.},
{-1.34742*10^-6, -1.11762*10^-6, -3.13724*10^-6, 0.895186}
```

This matrix **is not even symmetric**.  Much worse, *Mathematica* computes the matrix product

```
(square root).(square root)
```

as

```
{{0.548644, -0.209616, -0.588406, 0.}, 
{-0.234095, 0.607187, -0.545053, 0.}, 
{-0.103238, -0.0856309, 0.560987, 0.}, 
{-1.66133*10^-6, -1.37799*10^-6, -3.86814*10^-6, 0.801359}},
```

which is nowhere near the original matrix:

```
{{0.461964, -0.314388, -0.138647, -2.23115*10^-6}, 
{-0.314388, 0.510134, -0.128432, -2.06676*10^-6}, 
{-0.138647, -0.128432, 0.744719, -9.11454*10^-7}, 
{-2.23115*10^-6, -2.06676*10^-6, -9.11454*10^-7, 0.801359}}
```

Comment: If numerical stability is an issue the bug may not reproduce if you cut and past the numbers, although the linked notebook can be used to reproduce them.

Comment: I just let Mathematica 9 run through more 4 million iterations of your code, without finding a example where it fails. Although it is not indicated in the docs, `MatrixPower` must have changed between 8 and 9, as the handling of non positive definite matrices is now different. Maybe it was a bug and it has been fixed?

Comment: I just checked your notebook with *Mathematica* 8.0.4 under Windows 7 x64 and 4500000+ iterations of `FindCounterExample` still have not produced a "bad matrix".

Comment: Perhaps adding a `Monitor` for your `FindCounterExample` would be useful? I've not found anything - Mathematica version 9 on Mac.

Comment: Apparently this issue was fixed some time after version 7.01.0.  Could someone else with version 7 verify the bug?

Comment: Your function `FindCounterExample` does find a matrix on 7.0.1 ([here's an example](http://pastebin.com/ZaGsnBD5)), but taking the difference of that matrix with the square of its square root doesn't give a result outside of the precision of `$MachinePrecision`, so I don't see a problem there. In fact, doing `badmatrix = Map[SetPrecision[#, 40] &, badmatrix, {2}]` gives identically zero for the difference. Maybe [this tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/howto/ControlThePrecisionAndAccuracyOfNumericalResults.html) is worth a look?

Comment: Even if it works in most versions, is it documented somewhere that `MatrixPower` should work with non-integers?

Comment: If **MatrixPower** didn't work with non-integers then there should be an error message generated for the power p=1/2.  Indeed, it works >99.999% of the time, and it is only because I was applying the function millions of times in iterative optimization routines that I found examples where it fails spectacularly.

Comment: Teake Nutma:  **My example crashes `MatrixPower` even in the most significant digit of the largest entries of the matrix.**  Unlike in 99.999% of self-adjoint operators, `Eigensystem` returns eigenvectors which are very far from orthonormal: some nearly overlap.  To test whether the very sporatic `matrixpower` bug goes away at 40 digits of precision, you must change the precision **before** running the search routine `findcounterexample`.  Again, this is a numerical stability problem, so perturbing a counterexample however slightly (even by padding with zeros), will destroy the example.

Comment: Rojo: I should add that taking a square root of a positive semidefinite matrix is a common operation, for example it is used when one computes the polar decomposition of an arbitrary matrix.  More generally, if f:R->R is a function from the reals to the reals and A is a self-adjoint matrix, then one defines f(A) using the so-called "functional calculus" as follows: Take a spectral decomposition of A, with orthonormal eigenvectors. Then f(A) is computed by replacing each eigenvalue lamda_i by f(lamda_i). Note that if f=P is a polynomial then f(A) agrees with the usual notion of P(A).

Comment: I also recall seeing something about this on MathGroup, so I'm tagging this as a bug. I think it's due to an error in the Intel MKL, which *Mathematica* calls to calculate eigensystems of real matrices. Perhaps whoever wrote these functions ought to have read "Nineteen Dubious Ways to
Compute the Exponential of a Matrix" by Moler and van Loan. :) `Fourier` had similar trouble in 7.0.0, IIRC.

Comment: @OleksandrR. don't you think it should be documented to work on non-integers to deserve being called a bug? If so, I couldn't find it

Comment: @Rojo no; in fact, I think it should be documented specifically if valid exponents are limited to the integers, but this doesn't appear anywhere in the documentation, and  no message is produced if non-integers are used. The default position for all *Mathematica* functions seems to be that they can accept any type of input unless otherwise noted, and the only restriction given is that the matrix must be square. To lend additional weight to this argument, the problem is fixed in later versions, but the documentation isn't updated, and `MatrixPower` is listed as "last updated in 6".

Comment: @OleksandrR. I can't say I agree, or at least not yet given what I think to understand a bug is supposed to b). But I don't care much anyway. Since I said I disagree I must say why, but don't take it as a sign that I want to get in a long discussion for a tag. The function is explicitly described to work for naturals, negative exponents, for square matrices or sparse arrays, and that description cannot be applied to rationals, simply because you can't [evaluate the product of a matrix with itself 1/2 times](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MatrixPower.html)

Comment: @OleksandrR. Furthermore, the operation "matrix power" on rationals might be common and natural for us but [I am not sure](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MatrixPower.html) [it is standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Powers_of_matrices) to think of it as the same operation. Furthermore, if given a symbolic exponent, it expands it assuming an integer. The help uses the quite standard for integer `n` as variable name. The fact that the documentation isn't updated when the issue was fixed doesn't give weight to the argument: it wouldn't be updated on anything undocumented

Comment: I'm not saying it shouldn't be documented to work and actually work, or that if it is not supposed to, it shouldn't have better argument checking, but unless lack of good input checking is enough to call it a bug, I am not sure it should be called a bug.

Comment: @Rojo I understand your point of view. Although I mostly disagree, without getting into a detailed discussion, I think it's better to remove the tag. Although I'd personally still consider it a (very likely if not absolutely certain) bug, since the tag is meant to be used by community consensus, I can't justify adding it on my own initiative when others legitimately disagree. Incidentally, the matrix square root has been studied widely, and I agree with OP that this is likely just a numerical stability issue, perhaps due to special-casing this computation to avoid using the more general SVD.

Comment: Will those of you who claim that one cannot take the square root of a matrix PLEASE Google "square root of a matrix". THIS IS A STANDARD OPERATION IN LINEAR ALGEBRA.  Furthermore, it works correctly on positive semidefinite matrices 99.99% of the time in version 7.0.

Comment: @JTyson, ping whoever you are referring to. I saw noone implying that. In fact, not sure if this exists in v7 but there's ``LinearAlgebra`MatrixSqrt`` to try. In v9 you can also do `MatrixFunction[Sqrt,...]`. Most undocumented functions, such as the one I just mentioned, might work 99.99% but I believe it's unfair to publicly tag as a bug those times that they don't.

Comment: @Rojo I was referring to your statement "because you can't evaluate the product of a matrix with itself 1/2 times", which someone could just as well falsely claim about real numbers. Neither the documentation, the error messages generated by the function, nor the functionality in 99.99% of cases indicate that it shouldn't be used for p=1/2, which is probably the most common use of `MatrixPower'.   This is clearly a bug, I don't see why you stubbornly call my claims "unfair".

Comment: I feel you didn't read me with attention or follow the link under that quote, and became aggressive. Let's stop this here, these comments aren't helpful to anyone. Don't take it personally, this was never about you. Of course it's a bug in the sense that whoever implemented it didn't intend it to fail. Welcome to the site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I consider this question to be answered by the comments above that this bug in *MATHEMATICA 7* was fixed in later versions.