# Eigenvalues of large matrix

Tags: matrix, eigenvalues

Consider the following code

```
zx = Table[Tan[7/9 (i + j)], {i, 100}, {j, 100}];

Eigenvalues[N[zx]]
```

Every time I run this code I get new sets of eigenvalues. Can anyone tell why this is happening?

Comment: there is nothing random in your code. So for same input, the output should be the same. Can't reproduce. Try with clean Kernel? Can you show a screen shot showing 2 runs and they produce different output?  ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mDJyj.png)

Comment: Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Please find the screenshot at [link] (https://imgur.com/ILWuR0K)

Comment: it seems there was a bug in version 7.0. Can't find exact reference, but googling around there are some threads that talk about problems with eigenvalues/eigenvector in version 7. So I am sure this was a bug. But it is fixed now. It is always a good idea to mention which version you are using. Version 7 is 10 years old. This is like a century in human life. You might want to upgrade if you can.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment

Comment: related https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28890/2079

Comment: btw see if extended precision helps ( `Eigenvalues[N[zx, 20]]` ).  The v10 result has all but two values approximately +/- 2007 fwiw. (the other two are ~0.003 and ~64.)